# printf get executed twice if 50+ characters are entered

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement

Okay, quick context. This program needs to read up to 50 characters, display a menu and do functions. First function is searching something given by the user in the 50 character array it made earlier. Edit: Right now everything works as intended, except if you input 50 or more characters, the "menu" print happens twice.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int search(char arr[], int size1);
int main(){
    int fun, funct, i, size1, quit=0, c;
    char arr[50];
    printf("Please input up to 50 characters.\n");
    fgets(arr, 51, stdin);
    size1=strlen(arr);
    while (quit==0){
        printf("Please choose a function:\n1. Search for 
        character.\n2. Replace character.\n3. Look for 
        palindrome.\n4. Quit.\n");
        scanf("%d", &fun);
        while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' );
        switch (fun){
            case 1:
                funct=search(arr,size1);
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                quit=1;
                printf("Now quitting...");
                break;
        }
    }
}
int search(char arr[], int size1){
    char sear[50];
    int i, j, e, size2=60, foundn=0, pos[50], y=0, b, m;
    while (size2>size1){
        printf("Input up to %d characters to search.\n", size1);
        gets(sear);
        size2=strlen(sear);
        if (size2>size1){
            printf("Input longer than %d characters.\n", size1);
        }
    }
    for (m=0;m<50;m++){
        pos[m]=100;
    }
    for (j=0;j<size1;j++){
        if (arr[j]==sear[0]){
            e=j;
            for (i=1;i<size2;i++){
                e++;
                if (arr[e]==sear[i]){
                    if (i==(size2-1)){
                        foundn++;
                        pos[y]=j;
                        y++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (foundn>0){
        printf("Searched characters appear %d times in position(s): 
        ",foundn);
        for (b=0;pos[b]!=100;b++){
            printf("%d.\n", pos[b]);
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Characters do not appear in string.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: One issue: `size2` is an uninitialised variable. So `while (size2>size1)` is using an indeterminate value and the result is undefined behaviour. "*I tried the logic with pen and paper*". Good start. The next step is to debug the running  program. Use a debugger to step thru the code and examine it as it runs.

Comment: When the first iteration of `while (size2>size1)` is executed `size2` is uninitialized. You should read [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: `goto menu;` Using `goto` like this is bad practice and strongly discouraged. Write and call a function instead or use a proper loop construct like `while`.

Comment: There are valid uses for `goto`. This is not one of them.

Comment: First of all thanks everyone for the replies. Now for the size2 I just forgot to initialise it, i wanted it to be something like 60 just so it enters the while once. I've read all about fgets and gets, so I should swap the gets with fgets(sear, size1, stdin)? Should work, I'll try it. As for the goto, I know it's bad to use, but for some reason I just couldn't get the while loop to work. I had while(quit=o) {switch...} but the program just didn't work.

Comment: After trying with fgets instead of gets and while instead of goto I got these results: with fgets when I enter more than the maximum size it outputs some weird symbols and stuff, which I'd like to avoid. Figured out the while, removed goto, will update code

Comment: Unrelated: `char arr[50]; ... fgets(arr, 51, stdin);` is an accident waiting to happen. Either increase the size of the array (`char arr[51];`) or decrease the maximum amount read be `fgets()` (`fgets(arr, 50, stdin);`). Even better: use `sizeof` inside fgets: `fgets(arr, sizeof arr, stdin);`

Comment: Reason i put 51 in fgets is because I read it also stores \n, but I guess if the user inputs 51 characters then it all goes downhill huh. Will do

Comment: with sizeof if you input 50 characters, it will store 49 and also somehow break the program. same with my 51, but it stores 50 characters instead. When I say break, it prints the "menu" twice before letting the user choose an action. After that program works as intended, but menu is printed twice the first time it's printed

Comment: If there's more input than will fit in the buffer, `fgets` leaves the rest on standard input.  So it will try to read some portion of the remaining input line as `fun`.  That won't work, so `fun` will contain a random value, which probably won'g be 1 or 4, so you'll take another trip around your `while (quit==0)` loop, and prompt for more input.

Comment: It's a good habit to always check `scanf`'s return value: `int r = scanf("%d", &fun); if(r != 1) printf("invalid input\n");`

Comment: Hmm I see, yea it appears that exactly what you said happens Steve. How would one go about fixing that though?

Comment: regarding: `fgets(arr, 51, stdin);`  This is an error.  because there are only 50 characters in the input buffer, not 51

Comment: regarding `gets(sear);`  the function has been depreciated for many years and completely removed from the language around 2009.  suggest using `fgets()`  instead of `gets()`

Comment: regarding: `size2=strlen(sear);`  the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`

Comment: regarding: `while(quit=o) {switch...}`  the `quit=0` is an assignment, not a comparison..  Suggest:  `quit == 0`

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help! The program now works exactly like I need it to. Except that if I input more than 50 characters, it then crashes upon entering less than 50.